# is listening to an event of a base class safe?

Tags: c#, events

```
base.event += this.EventHandler()
```

is this code safe ? 
will it cause a leak ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better practice to override the method that fires the event, for example:

```
protected override OnClick(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnClick(sender,e);

   // Your code here, or before the base call depending how you want it to operate
}
```

Of course if it doesn't offer you this method (although it really should) you will have to stick to binding to the `Event` itself.

Answer (score 2):

Listening to base class events is code safe, won't cause memory leaks.

You can have a look [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy3sefw3(VS.80).aspx) to do it properly, though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is fine, as essentially you are just creating a reference to yourself.

You only need to worry about memory leaks if you create an event from an external object.